# How to join table once to get 2 different params with condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which contains vocabulary with terms. I need to create result entity which contains 2 different terms from one table.

Example:

`vocabulary`

| id | term_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Term 1 |
| 2 | Term 2 |
| 3 | Term 3 |

`change`

| id | new_term | old_term |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |

So I made:

```
SELECT
   changeTerms.id AS id,
   newTerms.term_name AS new_term_name,
   oldTerms.term_name AS old_term_name
FROM change changeTerms
   LEFT JOIN vocabulary newTerms ON changeTerms.new_term = newTerms.id
   LEFT JOIN vocabulary oldTerms ON changeTerms.old_term = oldTerms.id
WHERE changeTerms.id = #{id}
```

Than I send an id parameter 1,2,3 to get:

| id | new_term_name | old_term_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Term 3 | Term 1 |
| 2 | Term 2 | Term 1 |
| 3 | Term 1 | Term 2 |

**My question is**: Is there a way to get the above data without having to re-JOIN into the same table multiple times? Unfortunately I found only that solution - to make multiple joins.

P.S. The table I'm working with may have queries where there are 5-7 joins, I think the difference with the table in the example is small, but still

Comment: Please **Edit** your question and use the tag which correspond to your database: MySQL, MariaDB, PgSQL, etc. [tag:sql] may be too vague for your question.

Comment: Joining on each column is correct. What is the problem with your query?

Comment: Multiple JOINs on the same table is this acceptable? Are there any negative consequences in terms of the database for such a syntax? @Stu

Comment: Some of my colleagues said that it is possible to use a solution better than multi JOIN, so I asked this question here

Comment: you can use two correlated subqueries, but if this is better, is hard to tell as far i i know both solutions need the  same time to process

Comment: On some forums they write that a join is almost always faster than a subquery, but the server may freeze if there are a lot of joins. In a real table with which I am currently working, about 5-7 joins in a same query maximum @nbk

Comment: Multiple joins is fine, it is your where criteria that is questionable.

Comment: Ok, I'll write your answer here than. Thank you all for clearing my doubts.

Comment: How you express your query sematically, whether with a `join` keyword or a sub-query with a correlation, it is irrelevant until you examine the execution plan; the plan will always have to join the tables whether you use the `join` condition or not and the plans would probably be identical. SQL is a *declarative* language - you describe what you want, not how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple JOINs on the same table is correct and normal